# Intergrating Rails with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova

I'm now making a hybrid app with Vue.js/Cordova/Phonegap + Rails 5 api.
I've searched a lot about this and just following the existing path.

But I'm wondering why I can't directly integrate rails with cordova and couldn't find any explanation about this.
I think Vue.js's component way could be similarly made by Rails' partial render. If this integration is possible it would be much easier for rails developer to make SPA without additional frontend framwork.
As far as I understand, cordova itself is a webview, then why is this impossible?
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: welp, rails(not ruby) needs a server to run because it's designed as backend framework. Obviously, it doesn't fit into cordova. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @kasperite Thanks, it's simple and clear. But if cordova is conceptually a webview, then why can't we have server inside cordova? Is web view different from web browser where we can run rails server?